# How to check if key matches with paramvalue , get the object value using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, for-loop, object

I have an object and would like to know if an object property `key` matches with `param` then return the value using JavaScript:

```
var options = {
  "GROUP_X": "Group X",
  "GROUP_Y": "Group Y",
  "GROUP_Z": "Group Z"
}

var param = "GROUP_Y"
```

I tried:

```
options.forEach(e=> e.value === param);

// cannot use options.GROUP_Y since param is dynamic
```

Expected Output:

```
Group Y
```

Comment: `options[param]`.

Comment: If you _want_ output, you need to _make_ output at some point. Which your foreach callback function there is not currently doing at all. You loop over your items, you check your condition - and then you do nothing at all, when it matched.

Comment: Plus, `GROUP_Y` and `GROUP Y` are not the same thing.